# Epsilon Delta limit of absolute values?

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

I'm pretty new to Epsilon Delta limits, and I came across a problem that asked me to take the absolute value of a function. Namely $lim_{x\to a} \mid f(x) - g(x)\mid$, where $lim_{x\to a} f(x) = C, \lim_{x\to a} g(x) = D$. How should I go about proving that the limit is $\mid C-D \mid$, using the Epsilon Delta definition of a limit? Thanks!

Comment: just prove that for each function F such that $\lim_{x \to a} F(x) = L$ you have $\lim_{x \to a} |F(x)| = |L|$, and then put F = f - g

Comment: Are you constrained to use the epsilon-delta definition, or can you use limit laws that treat the difference and composition of two functions with limits?

Comment: Assuming that the difference of two functions limit law is out of bounds, you have that $| ~[f(x) - g(x)] ~- ~[C-D] ~| ~\leq ~| ~f(x) - C ~| ~+ ~| ~g(x) - D ~|$, by the triangle inequaliy: $|r + s| \leq |r| + |s|.$

Answer (score 2):

We need to show that $$\forall\varepsilon>0, \exists\delta>0\text{ such that }0<|x-a|<\delta\implies||f(x)-g(x)|-|C-D||<\varepsilon.$$

We know that

\begin{align*}
&\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists\delta_1>0\text{ such that }0<|x-a|<\delta_1\implies|f(x)-C|<\frac\varepsilon2\text{, and}\\
&\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists\delta_2>0\text{ such that }0<|x-a|<\delta_2\implies|g(x)-D|<\frac\varepsilon2
\end{align*}

> Question 1: Why are we allowed to use $\frac\varepsilon2$ instead of $\varepsilon$?

Set $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$, and suppose $0<|x-a|<\delta$. Then the above two statements still hold with $\delta$ instead of $\delta_1$ or $\delta_2$.

> Question 2: Why do the two above statements hold for $\delta$?

Now,

\begin{align*}
||f(x)-g(x)|-|C-D||&\leq|(f(x)-g(x))-(C-D)|\\
&=|(f(x)-C)-(g(x)-D)|\\
&\leq|f(x)-C|+|g(x)-D|\\
&<\frac\varepsilon2+\frac\varepsilon2\\
&=\varepsilon.
\end{align*}

> Question 3: Why is $||f(x)-g(x)|-|C-D||\leq|(f(x)-g(x))-(C-D)|$?

Comment: Hi! Thanks so much. I was wondering why it follows from the initial statement that $\mid f(x) - C \mid < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, and similarily $\mid g(x) - D \mid < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Thanks!

Comment: @ElmerCado I had a mistake in the proof. See the edit!